# Propel (PostgreSQL) syntax error at or near "."

Tags: php, postgresql, propel

I have a database set up (work in progress with currently only two tables: user and email) and integrated with Propel.  When registering a user I check to make sure that the email does not already exist (either as a current email in the email table or an original email in the user database).

To do this simply with propel, I use the following:

```
if(EmailQuery::create()->filterByCurrent(TRUE)->findOneByEmailAddress($email) != NULL) {
    // email address being used currently
} else if(UserQuery::create()->findOneByOriginalEmail($email) != NULL) {
    // email address claimed on account already
}
```

The first query works fine, but the second query generates and error: `Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "."`  The SQL query generated by Propel looks like the following:

`SELECT user.id, user.original_email, user.password, user.accept_terms, user.paid, user.customer_id, user.trial_end, user.created_at, user.updated_at, user.ip_address FROM user WHERE user.original_email=:p1 LIMIT 1`

If I copy and paste this into phpPgAdmin, it returns the same error (and points to each . in between user and the column).  I am new to PostgreSQL, is there some syntax piece I am missing?  All other Propel query builders I have used worked without a hitch.

Comment: `user` might be a reserved word; try `"user".(whatever)`.

Comment: @minitech that worked, I will rename my tables.  Can you add this as an answer so I can select you?

Comment: @minitech: not *might*: **is**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from `minitech`'s comment.

`user` is a reserved ANSI SQL term.  Either `SELECT "user".id FROM "user"` has to be used or table must be renamed.  I renamed the table to `account`, and all is well.

Comment: Just to be clear, that must be a PostgreSQL reserved word as I am able to use `user` without quotes in MySQL. Also, you (@Sam) may want to add this as an [issue in Propel](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues). (Seems it could be solved by quoting the table name in the generated SQL.)

Comment: Will update my answer and add that as an issue, thanks for the extra info. It was definitely an annoying error to debug that could of been avoided by Propel.

Comment: @jakerella: it's a reserved word as per ANSI SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: can you provide a link to the documentation? Whether it is in a spec is one thing, but in practice it appears that MySQL does not reserve it (or is smart enough to know when it isn't being used as a keyword).

And really, this should be submitted as a Propel bug, the SQL generated should be quoting table names (and field names for that matter).

Comment: @jakerella: see here: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt and here: https://kb.askmonty.org/en/sql-language-elements/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. (FYI for others, search for "reserved" in those docs to find a full list.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As far as I know MySQL does not do a very good job at staying up to SQL standards.